# Toggleable sidebar inside a toggleable Topbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, sidebar

**Hey there,**

i need some toogleable sidetabs inside a toggleable topbar. Right now every sidetab is opened if i click on a button of the topbar.

I Just want to open the first sidetab and set it to active if a button of the topbar is clicked.

Even if one sidetab is choosen, the function has to be restarted if a button of the topbar is clicked. (Have a look at the code Snippet)

**Please help me out. Thank's a lot!**

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}


function openCard(evt, cardName) {
    var i, cardcontent, cardlinks;
    cardcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("cardcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < cardcontent.length; i++) {
        cardcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    cardlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("cardlinks");
    for (i = 0; i < cardlinks.length; i++) {
        cardlinks[i].className = cardlinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cardName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

 // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
 document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tablinks {
 width: auto;
 height: 5rem;
    float: left;
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-right: 2%;
 
 border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
 
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tablinks:hover {
    color: #BD1521;
 transition: 0.35s all ease;
}

/* Set default styles for tab content */
.tabcontent {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 69vh;
 padding-top: 3%;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.tabtext{
 width: 68%;
}



div.card {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 30rem;
    height: 300px;
}

.card img{
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.card button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.card button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
div.card button.active {
    background-color: #000;
 color: white;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.cardcontent {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 2%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 margin-left: 1%;
    width: 71.7%;
    height: auto;
 
 color: black;
 text-align: left;
 line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
 
     
  <div class="tab">
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Reparatur')" id="defaultOpen">REPARATUR &amp; INSTANDSETZUNG</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Lackierung')">LACKIERUNG &amp; FOLIERUNG</button>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  <div id="Reparatur" class="tabcontent">
   

   <div class="card">
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con1.0')">Bagatell- und
        Blechschäden</button>
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con2.0')">Parkdellen</button>
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con3.0')">Hagelschäden</button>
   </div>

   
   <div id="con1.0" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Zu unserem Stammkundenkreis gehören renommierte Autohäuser sowie eine Vielzahl von Privat-
        Kunden,die wir mit bester Qualitätsarbeit und unseren Serviceleistungen seit vielen Jahren 
        bedienen.Wir freuen uns auf Sie!
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="con2.0" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Wir sind ein zertifizierter KFZ Meisterbetrieb in den Bereichen Lack, Hagel, Dellen und Karosserie. Mit Qualität, Kompetenz und Service 
     schaffen wir zufriedene Kunden.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="con3.0" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Jeder Auftrag wird mit größter Sorgfalt ausgeführt. Die Reparaturen werden von unseren kompetenten Teams zuverlässig und präzise ausgeführt, so wie komplizierte Lackierungen oder   
     umfangreiche Arbeiten an der Karosserie Ihres Fahrzeugs.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   
  </div>
   
    
      
    
  <div id="Lackierung" class="tabcontent">
  
   <div class="card">
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con1.1')">Spot- &amp; Teillackierung</button>
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con2.1')">Komplettlackierung</button>
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con3.1')">Autofolierung</button>
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con4.1')">Kratzerentfernung</button>
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con5.1')">Lackpolitur</button>
    <button class="cardlinks" onclick="openCard(event, 'con6.1')">Versiegelung</button>
   </div>
    
    
   <div id="con1.1" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Zu unserem Stammkundenkreis gehören renommierte Autohäuser sowie eine Vielzahl von Privat-Kunden,die wir mit bester Qualitätsarbeit und unseren Serviceleistungen seit vielen Jahren bedienen.Wir freuen uns auf Sie!
    </p>
   </div>
  
   <div id="con2.1" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Wir sind ein zertifizierter KFZ Meisterbetrieb in den Bereichen Lack, Hagel, Dellen und Karosserie. Mit Qualität, Kompetenz und Service 
     schaffen wir zufriedene Kunden.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="con3.1" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Jeder Auftrag wird mit größter Sorgfalt ausgeführt. Die Reparaturen werden von unseren kompetenten Teams zuverlässig und präzise ausgeführt, so wie komplizierte Lackierungen oder   
     umfangreiche Arbeiten an der Karosserie Ihres Fahrzeugs.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="con4.1" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Zu unserem Stammkundenkreis gehören renommierte Autohäuser sowie eine Vielzahl von Privat-Kunden,die wir mit bester Qualitätsarbeit und unseren Serviceleistungen seit vielen Jahren bedienen.Wir freuen uns auf Sie!
    </p>
   </div>
  
   <div id="con5.1" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Wir sind ein zertifizierter KFZ Meisterbetrieb in den Bereichen Lack, Hagel, Dellen und Karosserie. Mit Qualität, Kompetenz und Service 
     schaffen wir zufriedene Kunden.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="con6.1" class="cardcontent">
    <p> Jeder Auftrag wird mit größter Sorgfalt ausgeführt. Die Reparaturen werden von unseren kompetenten Teams zuverlässig und präzise ausgeführt, so wie komplizierte Lackierungen oder   
     umfangreiche Arbeiten an der Karosserie Ihres Fahrzeugs.
    </p>
   </div>
   
   
  </div>
```

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your goal here, but it sounds like what you're trying to do is achievable with [Bootstrap navbars](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/). Are you specifically trying to make this custom-programmed?

Comment: Yes, i try to make it custom-programmed.

Comment: I already have a custom-programmed main navigation on my website but not with bootstrap. This is only for my content on a single page.